# Mutli line comments is not showing up in Email notification from the Manual intervention job in ADO Release Pipeline

Tags: powershell, api, azure-devops, write-host

[EMail Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH9FG.png)Currently working on a ADO release Pipeline. The First job is a Manual Intervention Job, where a user is notified to approve/Reject the deployment with a comment. The next stage sends out an email notification with the user provided comment and other details. My issue is, if the comments are multi-lined, apart from the first line, other lines does not show up in email notification. Below is my setup using powershell and Send email task

**Powershell setup -**

```
dir
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$(MY_PAT)"))
$url = "$(System.TeamFoundationServerUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/Release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)/manualinterventions?api-version=6.0"
$header = @{ Authorization = "Basic $B64Pat" }
$release = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
write-host $release.value.comments
$comment = $release.value.comments
write-host "$comment"
$status = $release.value.status

**Setup variables for comments and Approval status**
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=release-scope]$comment"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=approval-status;]$status"

Write-Host $comment

Write-Host $release.value
```

Assigning variable comment value to release-scope and using it below in the send email task

**Send email Task**

```
Email-Body - in between <p></p> <h2></h2>

Hi Team,

This email is to notify that team has reviewed deployment request and provided their go/no-go decision. Please find details below.

Release Information:

BSA Approval Status : $(approval-status)

Documentation URLs / Comments : $(release-scope)

Here $(release-scope) are the comments provided by user in Manual intervention job. If the comments are like below
```

Line 1

Line 2

Then it prints only Line 1 in the email notification.

Comment: `$comment -replace '\r?\n', '<br />'` ?

Comment: Hi, Can you elaborate on your answer please.

Comment: You are obviously sending an email in HTML format, so replace the newlines in the $comment into HTML newlines (`<br />`). Otherwise, newlines will be normalized in HTML

Comment: Did you mean changing this <br>Documentation URLs / Comments : $(release-scope)</br> ?  If so it is still showing only the 1st line <p>Hi Team,</p>

<p>This email is to notify that  team has reviewed deployment request and provided their go/no-go decision. Please find details below.</p>

<h2>Release Information: </h2>

<br>BSA Approval Status : $(approval-status)</br>
<br>Documentation URLs / Comments : $(release-scope)</br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mutli line comments is not showing up in Email notification from the Manual intervention job in ADO Release Pipeline

That because **the variable does not support multi-line in the value**.

When you setup variables for comments and Approval status by logging command:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=release-scope]$comment"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=approval-status;]$status"
```

It **only set the first line** to the variable `release-scope`. That the reason why only Line 1 in the email notification.

You could add a command line task in the pipeline to output the value of `release-scope`.

To resolve this issue, we could use powershell task to replace the `\n` with `,` to remove the wrap:

```
$NewComment = $comment  -replace "`n",", " -replace "`r",", "

write-host "this is NewComment $NewComment "

#**Setup variables for comments and Approval status**
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=release-scope]$NewComment "
```

Now, we could get the value `release-scope` of is:

```
testline1, testline2
```

instead of only `testline1`.

If you want to stick to the newline format in your email notification, you need send the e-mail in the powershell task with scripts instead of email task.

You could check the document [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.1) for some more details.